# Find out if user got permission to select/update/... a table/function/... in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, metadata, privileges, information-schema

What is the recommended way to figure out if a user got a certain right (e.g. select or execute) on a certain class (e.g. table or function) in PostgreSQL?

At the moment I got something like

```
aclcontains(
    someColumnWithAclitemArray,
    makeaclitem(userOid,grantorOid,someRight,false))
```

but it's terrible since I have to check for every `grantorOid` that is possible and for every `userOid` the user can belong to.

On a related note: what are the possible rights you can test for?
I haven't found any documentation but reading the source code I guess:

```
INSERT
SELECT
UPDATE
DELETE
TRUNCATE
REFERENCES
TRIGGER
EXECUTE
USAGE
CREATE
CONNECT
```

There also seems to be a `CREATE TEMP` right, but I can't figure out the correct text to use in the `makeaclitem`-function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found that a better approach (and I seem to remember this was taken from some queries built into psql, or maybe the information_schema views) is to use the `has_*_privilege` functions, and simply apply them to a set of all possible combinations of user and object. This will take account of having access to an object via some group role as well.

For example, this will show which users have which access to non-catalogue tables and views:

```
select usename, nspname || '.' || relname as relation,
       case relkind when 'r' then 'TABLE' when 'v' then 'VIEW' end as relation_type,
       priv
from pg_class join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace,
     pg_user,
     (values('SELECT', 1),('INSERT', 2),('UPDATE', 3),('DELETE', 4)) privs(priv, privorder)
where relkind in ('r', 'v')
      and has_table_privilege(pg_user.usesysid, pg_class.oid, priv)
      and not (nspname ~ '^pg_' or nspname = 'information_schema')
order by 2, 1, 3, privorder;
```

The possible privileges are detailed in the description of the `has_*_privilege` functions at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE.

'CREATE TEMP' is a database-level privilege: it permits a user to use a `pg_temp_*` schema. It can be tested with `has_database_privilege(useroid, datoid, 'TEMP')`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the ["Access Privilege Inquiry Functions"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-ACCESS-TABLE) and also the ["GRANT"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) reference page.

Answer (score -1):

Because Redshift is supporting `values()` [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233519/how-to-select-multiple-rows-filled-with-constants-in-amazon-redshift) in `INSERT INTO` queries, the below query can be used with the obviously not-so-nice `union all select`.

```
select usename, nspname || '.' || relname as relation,
       case relkind when 'r' then 'table' when 'v' then 'view' end as relation_type,
       priv
from pg_class join pg_namespace on pg_namespace.oid = pg_class.relnamespace,
     pg_user,
     (select 'select' as priv,1 as privorder union all select 'insert',2 union all select 'update',3 union all select 'delete',4)
where relkind in ('r', 'v')
      and has_table_privilege(pg_user.usesysid, pg_class.oid, priv)
      and not (nspname ~ '^pg_' or nspname = 'information_schema')
order by 2, 1, 3, privorder;
```

Edit:
Also, I realized, that in our db Dataiku creates tables that can have CAPITAL letter in them, so, if `table not exist` error happens, you should use the `lower()` function

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).