# How to select multiple rows filled with constants in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, set-returning-functions

I have already tried the common PostgreSQL answer, but seems like it doesn't work with Redshift:

```
SELECT  * FROM VALUES (1) AS q (col1);

ERROR: 42883: function values(integer) does not exist
```

I need this because for some reason I can't use `UNION ALL`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just ran into this myself. Here are the docs on which Postgres features are unsupported in Redshift: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The correct **Postgres** syntax would be:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1)) AS q (col1);
```

A set of parentheses was missing.

But **Redshift** does not support free-standing `VALUES` expressions (outside of `INSERT` commands). So, for a **single row**:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1) AS q (col1);
```

For **multiple rows** (without using `UNION ALL` like requested) you can use a temporary table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE q(col1 int);
INSERT INTO q(col1)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);

SELECT * FROM q;
```

[The manual:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_AS.html)

> A temporary table is automatically dropped at the end of the session
> in which it was created.

If `UNION ALL` is an option:

```
SELECT 1 AS col1
UNION ALL SELECT 2
UNION ALL SELECT 3;
```