# Error while using regexp_split_to_table (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: amazon-redshift, set-returning-functions

I have the same question as this:
 [Splitting a comma-separated field in Postgresql and doing a UNION ALL on all the resulting tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232572/splitting-a-comma-separated-field-in-postgresql-and-doing-a-union-all-on-all-the)
Just that my 'fruits' column is delimited by '|'. When I try:

```
SELECT 
    yourTable.ID, 
    regexp_split_to_table(yourTable.fruits, E'|') AS split_fruits
FROM yourTable
```

I get the following:

> ```
> ERROR: type "e" does not exist
> ```

Q1. What does the `E` do? I saw some examples where `E` is not used. The official docs don't explain it in their "quick brown fox..." example.

Q2. How do I use '|' as the delimiter for my query?

Edit: I am using PostgreSQL 8.0.2. unnest() and regexp_split_to_table() both are not supported.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### A1

`E` is a prefix for Posix-style escape strings. You don't normally need this in modern Postgres. Only prepend it if you want to interpret special characters in the string. Like `E'\n' for a newline char.`Details and links to documentation:

- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-varchar-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql/12320729#12320729)
- [SQL select where column begins with \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9141521/sql-select-where-column-begins-with/9141630#9141630)

`E` is pointless noise in your query, but it should still work. [The answer you are linking to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232572/splitting-a-comma-separated-field-in-postgresql-and-doing-a-union-all-on-all-the) is not very good, I am afraid.

#### A2

Should work as is. But better without the `E`.

```
SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(fruits, '|') AS split_fruits
FROM   tbl;
```

For simple delimiters, you don't need expensive regular expressions. This is typically faster:

```
SELECT id, unnest(string_to_array(fruits, '|')) AS split_fruits
FROM   tbl;
```

In Postgres 9.3+ you'd rather use a `LATERAL` join for set-returning functions:

```
SELECT t.id, f.split_fruits
FROM   tbl t
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(fruits, '|')) AS f(split_fruits)
                                                                   ON true;
```

Details:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)
- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

#### Amazon Redshift is not Postgres

It only implements a reduced set of features as [documented in its manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html). In particular, there are **no** table functions, including the essential functions `unnest()`, `generate_series()` or `regexp_split_to_table()` when working with its "compute nodes" (accessing any tables).

You should go with a **normalized table layout** to begin with (extra table with one fruit per row).

Or here are some options to create a *set* of rows in Redshift:

- [How to select multiple rows filled with constants in Amazon Redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233519/how-to-select-multiple-rows-filled-with-constants-in-amazon-redshift/28991832#28991832)

This **workaround** should do it:

1. Create a **table of numbers**, with at least as many rows as there can be fruits in your column. Temporary or permanent if you'll keep using it. Say we never have more than 9:

   ```
   CREATE TEMP TABLE nr9(i int);
   INSERT INTO nr9(i) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);
   ```
2. Join to the number table and use `split_part()`, which is [actually implemented in Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html):

   ```
   SELECT *, split_part(t.fruits, '|', n.i) As fruit
   FROM   nr9 n
   JOIN   tbl t ON split_part(t.fruits, '|', n.i) <> ''
   ```

Voilá.

Comment: Turns out I am using version 8.0.2. Any way to do the above on this version?

Comment: @Reise45: Redshift is not Postgres. It does not support table functions at all. I added a possible solution for Redshift.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately my data is too big and this function is too slow on RedShift. Taking the Redshift-S3-Python-S3-RedShift route.