# Postgres - Loop through a string entry and create join table

Tags: arrays, postgresql, loops, join

I have two tables like so:

books:

```
id | tags
---+---------------------------------------------------
1  | [philosophy.plato]
2  | [literature.history]
3  | [cultural_history.18th_century.16th_century.history]
```

tags:

```
id | name
---+---------------------------------------------------------
1  | literature
2  | history
3  | philosophy
4  | plato
```

And I am trying to create a join table to cross refer the items in books with their tags. Something like this....

books_tags:

```
book_id | tag_id
--------+---------------------------------------------------------
   1    | 3
   1    | 4
   2    | 1
   2    | 2
```

How can I take the books.tags string and convert it into an array, look up each item in the array, and insert it into the join table?

So far I have:

```
SELECT distinct(s.tag)
FROM books t, unnest(string_to_array(trim (t.tags, '[]'), '.')) s(tag);
```

Which splits in the string into an array, but how do I loop through each item and insert it into the join table?

Comment: what is your desire output? Insert? where?

Comment: I want to create the table books_tags as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining `unnest()` with `string_to_array()` (like you already had) is typically considerably faster than `regexp_split_to_table()`, because regular expressions are expensive. Compare:

- [Error while using regexp_split_to_table (Amazon Redshift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975066/error-while-using-regexp-split-to-table-amazon-redshift/28975313#28975313)

I suggest a `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-lateral-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

```
CREATE TABLE books_tags AS
SELECT b.id AS book_id, t.tag_id
FROM   books b, unnest(string_to_array(trim(b.tags, '[]'), '.')) x(tag)
JOIN   tags  t ON t.name = x.tag
-- GROUP BY 1, 2  -- only if there can be duplicates
-- ORDER BY 1, 2; -- optional, but probably good for performance
```

"name" is [not a reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) - but still a very bad choice for a column name because it's not descriptive. I would simply use "tag" for the name of a tag.

You probably want to add a unique constraint and foreign keys to complete the many-to-many relationship. More:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with such a query:

```
WITH books(id, tags) AS (
  VALUES (1::int4, 'philosophy.plato'::text),
    (2, 'literature.history'),
    (3, 'cultural_history.18th_century.16th_century.history')
), tags (id, "name") AS (
  VALUES (1, 'literature'),
    (2, 'history'),
    (3, 'philosophy'),
    (4, 'plato')
)
SELECT b.id book_id,
       t.id tag_id
  FROM (
    SELECT id, regexp_split_to_table(tags, E'\\.') tag
      FROM books) b
  JOIN tags t ON t."name"=b.tag;
```

Some notes:

1. It is not good to use `name` for the column — this is a reserved word. If you still wish to keep, it is better to use double quotes around it.
2. My `WITH` constructs match your tables and can be skipped in your case